# Different "Accept" HTTP Header sent by browser

Tags: http, internet-explorer, browser, https, outlook-web-app

According to my understanding, the "Accept" header(HTTP) is sent from the browser first time it access the resource [or when it makes the request]. For specific resources, browser adds the value as "image/*" and so on for other specific types. But how the webbrowser know for generic resource(such as home page).

When I am accessing OWA application: my browser **(IE in my case)** is ***not*** sending below values for the Accept header, which is required for the full functionality to work.:

> application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml,
>   image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*

but instead sending:

> Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*

Can someone tell me if I have to make any configuration changes to the browser. Or how can I achieve the same behaviour in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add the correspoding site to the local intranet zone, in security option of IE browser, those corresponding headers(long one) are being sent from the browser and application is working as expected.